# Decrypting EFS w/o altering timestamp - possible?

Tags: windows, filesystems, encryption, ntfs, encrypting-file-system

I'd like to decrypt some EFS-encrypted files, but I do not know how to do that without altering the timestamp. When encrypting/decrypting files, the modified-time is set to the current time. I'd like to preserve the original timestamp, as the *file content* have not really changed.

Is this possible? Solutions i don't think work

- copy to/from FAT (timestamp resolution differs)
- copy to from Samba share (same)
- programmatically copy original timestamp and reapply after decryption (possible, but need to handle decryption time which may vary)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work:

- Set up a network share on a remote machine with NTFS encryption *disabled* (run `"fsutil behavior set disableencryption 1"` ).
- Copy to/from it

Answer (score 0):

This might help, though I haven't tried it myself:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem`

`NtfsDisableLastAccessUpdate`

`Type: REG_DWORD`

`Value: 1`

If it doesn't exist you may have to create it.

You may also be able to use this command from the command prompt, with administrate privileges, of course:

`fsutil behavior set disablelastaccess`

Comment: I don't think this is related to my problem, I read the following "(NtfsDisableLastAccessUpdate)...Determines whether NTFS updates the last-access timestamp on each directory when it lists the directories on an NTFS volume."